# Center of gravity of a hollow tank

Tags: newtonian-gravity

I have to find the center of Gravity of a hollow oblong tank with 1 side missing. For installing lifting lugs x 4 on top which must align with the intersection point. (the tank will be lifted off the ground and must remain horizontal to the floor).

Tank dimensions are as follows; L = 3800mm, H = 2600mm, W = 1820mm
The side that is missing is 3800mm x 2600mm
The top of the tank is 3800mm x 1820mm

So i'm looking to be able to calculate how far off the center line of the tank the CoG is?

Thanks for you help and explanations in advance.

Mike